# ToList() responsibility for caller or callee?

Tags: c#, enumeration

Have a look at the following example:

```
public IEnumerable<LogEntry> GetLogs(string groupName)
{
    return _Db.Logs.Where(l => l.groupName == groupName);
}
```

Should I actually add ToList() before returning this method? Or is this the responsibility for the caller?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? And what's the context? There's no "one-size-fits-all" solution here.

Comment: Well, I thought was more of a generic programming question that would be applicable to C#, or Java. But most likely I was wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you will add `ToList()` before returning - it will cause **full enumeration** of your enumerable.

If you will return `IEnumerable` instead of converting it to list - then it will be enumerated by caller on the first use of it.

So if your data size in `_Db.logs` is large - possibly it's better to enumerate it on caller's size as caller will not nessesary enumerate whole set of data (depending on what caller plans to do with it).

Answer (score 1):

Converting your IEnumerable to a List would rob you of all the benefits of having an IEnumerable, mainly lazy evaluation. So, if your caller really wants to create a List, let him, but don't force him to.

Comment: There are valid situations where you may want to return a list masked as an enumerable. For example, you are getting the data from a database so want to retrieve it all before the connection is closed, but don't want to give the caller the impression they can affect future results by adding to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow people choose when to evaluate the query, return IEnumerable. If you specify IList as return type, you must evaluate the expression by calling ToArray() or ToList().

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use this method.
You should pass what you want and don't will loss control of data acquisition time.

```
public List<LogEntry> GetLogs(Expression<Predicate<LogEntry>> where)
{
    return _Db.Logs.Where(where).ToList();
}
```

}